# checking if a value exists in another table within the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to query names from table1 and also find if a name exists in table2. I have the following query but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions what I did wrong?

```
select A.name, 
       CASE WHEN A.name in (select B.name in table2 B)
       THEN 'common'
       ELSE 'not common'
       END

from table1 A
```

Please note that I have to get "common" / "uncommon" from the select clause itself. I'm using postgres.

Comment: The suquery used in the `CASE` expression is syntactically incorrect. What error do you get when you execute the query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using subquery in SELECT CASE will cost more. Use left join instead like below

```
    select A.name, 
       CASE WHEN B.name IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'common'
       ELSE 'not common'
       END

    from table1 A
    left join table2 B
    on A.name = B.name
```

Comment: It will produce duplicate values in some cases.

Answer (score 24):

I would use EXIST instead of IN:

```
select
  A.name, 
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (select *
                 from table2 B
                 where B.name = A.name)
    THEN 'common'
    ELSE 'not common'
  END
from
  table1 A
```

Comment: What if I need to get values from another column from Table 2 as well (say Date) such that if the name is common in both tables, date value should be displayed in the result along with 'Common'/'Not Common'.

Comment: How optimised is it, I mean is it feasible if we are dealing with large number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `in` with `from` in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name,
    case
        when a.name in (select distinct name from table2) then 'common'
        else 'not common'
    end as new
from table1 a
```