# SQL sub-query check if data exists in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and the question may already exist in some form. I am developing a web app that displays cards that contain title,description and more information regarding a place, and with a sub-query fetches the image data regarding each place. PostgreSQL is used. I want to add a sub-query or join that gets which items are liked by the user from the ones selected(present in the favoritePlaces with the corresponding `user_id` and `place_id` received from the query). Sample dynamically generated query:

```
SELECT places.place_id,
       username,
       title,
       description,
       visible,
       score,
       placelocation,
       category,
       price,
       accessibility,
       places.date,
       dangerous,
       url,
       image_id
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM places
   GROUP BY place_id
   HAVING count(*) < 10) places
LEFT JOIN images ON images.place_id = places.place_id
WHERE description SIMILAR TO Concat('%', '', '%')
  AND placelocation =placelocation
  AND category =category
  AND price =price
  AND dangerous =dangerous
  AND accessibility =accessibility
  OR title SIMILAR TO Concat('%', '', '%')
  AND visible=TRUE
  AND placelocation =placelocation
  AND category =category
  AND price =price
  AND dangerous =dangerous
  AND accessibility =accessibility
```

The end goal is to have for each item whether it is liked or not(present in the the favoritePlaces table with regards to the current user). favoritePlaces Tables structure:
[image: structure]

I looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773730/14131447 but I am not sure how to implement it.

Sample data within the favoritePlaces table:
[image]

Comment: What does it mean "liked" in terms of your data?

Comment: @AtanasB, please give more details about desired output.  What does this meaning? "HAVING count(*) < 10)"

Comment: "HAVING count(*) < 10)" simply limits the number of rows

Comment: liked means present in the favoritePlaces with the corresponsing user id and place id received from the query

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by simply adding the case after the SELECT columns

```
    SELECT places.place_id,
       username,
       title,
       description,
       visible,
       score,
       placelocation,
       category,
       price,
       accessibility,
       places.date,
       dangerous,
       url,
       image_id,  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (select *
                 from "favoritePlaces"
                 where "favoritePlaces".place_id = places.place_id AND user_id=128
)
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM places
   GROUP BY place_id
   HAVING count(*) < 10) places
LEFT JOIN images ON images.place_id = places.place_id
WHERE description SIMILAR TO Concat('%', '', '%')
  AND placelocation =placelocation
  AND category =category
  AND price =price
  AND dangerous =dangerous
  AND accessibility =accessibility
  OR title SIMILAR TO Concat('%', '', '%')
  AND visible=TRUE
  AND placelocation =placelocation
  AND category =category
  AND price =price
  AND dangerous =dangerous
  AND accessibility =accessibility;
```